# Active Directory Authentication using OpenLDAP

Tags: c, authentication, active-directory, openldap

I am writing a authentication module in C to authenticate users using Active Directory Service and get that users groups list (i.e. memberOf attribute).

I have only the Active directory Server URI and the DOMAIN\Username and Password that the user use to login to a Windows workstation (Windows is configured to connect to the same Active directory Service for authentication)

The program that requires the above authentication module is written in C for a Linux platform and can use OpenLDAP for communicating with AD service.

Is there a way to do this?

It is prefered if the solutions provided did not require a directory wide search for the user's directory entry after the LDAP bind (most certainly not a search that may result in multiple entries).

Comment: Simply put, Is there a way to find the LDAP DN of the security principal (i.e. User directory entry) that was used to do the bind on a AD session.

Comment: Does the user name attribute and value show up in multiple branches of your directory? I.e. do you not have a single base DN that you can combine with the user name in your principal to construct the DN of the user?

Comment: The DN has multiple OUs that represent different companies of a company group. Their Windows logins (i.e. samAccountName or userPrincipalName) are not equal to the CN attribute of a User (i.e. CN is in the form of <FirstName><SPACE><SirName>)

Comment: As per your question. I cannot make the assumption that there will not be two users with same first name and sir-name in two of the companies of the group